# えらかない - strange conjugation of えらい

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language, particle-は, contractions, i-adjectives

I understand that えらい is an adjective which means distinguished/famous etc.
Then I came across this conversation

> 「おいらよりマシかぁ、なぁんだ、じゃあえらいなぁ。」
>
> 「別にえらかァないよ...」
>
> "Preferable to me!? What! Well, I'm distinguished."
>
> "You're not particularly distinguished."

(all the extra あ and ア are supposed to be in small font. Any one know how to do that?)

The second sentence led me to think that there must also be a verb えらく -> えらかない. But I can't find it in any dictionary. What's going on in the second sentence?

Comment: Regarding small fonts, append a 'l' or 'x' before the character you want to type, eg. ぁ and ァ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

えらかァない is a colloquial, collapsed way of saying えらくはない.
えらく(連用形/continuative form of えらい) + は(係助詞/binding particle) + negative ない

> 「おいらよりマシかぁ、なぁんだ、じゃあえらいなぁ。」
>   「別にえらかァないよ...」

"Better than me? Well, **you're** distinguished/great, then."
"**I'm** not particularly distinguished/great..."